# search in subfolders with recursive functions

Tags: c++, c, matlab, octave

I am writing a code in octave which is the same as well in matlab, with a recursive function. I have a lot of folders and subfolders and inside one of the subfolders, there is a folder which is called `img` and inside the `img` folder there are two image files which I read and calculate some data.

**Here is the code**:

```
function findin(folder)

foldername = 'img';
filetofind = '*.ppm';

scalefront = 0.05;
scaletop = 0.05;


dirinfo = dir(folder);
dirinfo(~[dirinfo.isdir]) = [];  %remove non-directories
tf = ismember( {dirinfo.name}, {'.', '..'});
dirinfo(tf) = [];  %remove current and parent directory.

for i=1:length(dirinfo)
  if strcmp(dirinfo(i).name, foldername)
   files = dir(fullfile(dirinf(i).name, filetofind));
   frontimage = strcat(files(1).name);
   topimage = strcat(files(2).name);
   Angle = getAngle(frontimage, scalefront, topimage, scaletop);
   printf('\nAngle for images %s and %s is: &f\n', frontimage, topimage, Angle);
  else
   findin(dirinfo(i).name);
  end
end
printf('done!');
endfunction
```

The problem is that the `if` statement never becomes `true` and in whatever folder I am, it just prints 'done!' according to the number of folders. This means that it doesn't do the recursive call.

Am i doing something wrong with the recursive call??

Comment: If the if is never true, then the problem must be in `strcmp(dirinfo(i).name, foldername)`

Comment: I think the problem is your recursion. Using relative path, for example `a` will always be interpreted as a subfolder of your current folder, it won't work for a subsubfolder `b\a`

Comment: btw: aren't you missing an 'o' here: files = dir(fullfile(dirinf(i).name, filetofind));

Comment: Unless you have a strong aversion against fast, safe and memory-efficient programs, don't use recursion for this.

Comment: Daniel is correct, your recursive call needs to be something like `findin(fullfile(pwd,dirinfo(i).name));` or `findin(fullfile(folder,dirinfo(i).name));`